# Add a way to scroll code

Tags: support, android-app, code-block, scrolling

It's currently impossible to read long lines of code in the Android app, as swiping will move from question to answer

Comment: Could you include a link to a question where this happens

Comment: Any question with code, really

Answer (score 5):

Ok, I'm dumb. One just needs to click on the code

Comment: You got there just before me